# An unexpected storyteller

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

Quietly, we entered right through yesterday's unit.
In our place, all seemed... distant... forgotten... gone.
How Jack knew Lucy zoned, Xavier could verify, but not match.

**What's "unusual" about the story?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The first letter of each word corresponds to the qwerty keyboard layout, there are 26 words in the story.

Comment: NIcely done! :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I'm missing a secondary layer, but I noticed:

> The story uses each letter of the English alphabet at least once!

Comment: That's a good start!