# An unexpected storyteller (2)

Tags: story, english, word-property

This puzzle is a little similar to a previous one of mine: [An unexpected storyteller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62479/an-unexpected-storyteller)

In the story, you are ultimately looking for 26 words. Although finding all the words is part of the puzzle, the real goal is to answer two main questions:

**1. What do all the words have in common?**

**2. What's special about the order of the words?**

> I once met a *deceiver*, who was arrested for not repaying *the money he owed*. In court, he was *formally accused* of the crime and despite trying to look *attractive*, he *spasmed* every time he lied. He had stolen an *old British coin*, but his alibi was that his mother had begun coughing *thick mucous from the lungs* after she was startled by an *apparition*.
>
> They called the owner of the *company* he worked for as witness, he told the court that the man had once left his *Dutch rice table* dinner early and he was a *scoundrel* for doing so. The judge reminded the owner that they were not here to *chat* and so the witness told him that had a condition where *his brain could not forget* and so he knew it was a *French man*, or possibly *more than one person*, who stole the *brilliant blue gem*.
>
> After hearing such nonsense, the judge was forced to release the man, who left for a gambling ship to play *a card game which sounded like 500*. It was held in the *crew's living quarters*, with a man who was *British nobility* and a *missionary* who had *deposits on his teeth*. The man produced a *coin worth 10 of what he was accused of stealing*, and made *double* his money on the game.
>
> He decided to spend his winnings on a trip to *a French suburb*, where he could *ask a higher power for help* and eventually *meet up* with the woman of his dreams

*BONUS POINT: Where did I get the list of words from?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that all of the words have in common is

> that they all contain a silent letter (for some stretching of the definition of silent, e.g. PRAY).

The order they are in is

> the alphabetic order of the silent letter

So:

1. deceiver

> CHE(A)T

2. the money he owed

> DE(B)T

3. formally accused

> INDI(C)TED

4. attractive

> HAN(D)SOME

5. spasmed

> S(E)IZED

6. old British coin

> HAL(F)PENNY (actually the L is silent, too)

7. thick mucous from the lungs

> PHLE(G)M

8. apparition

> G(H)OST

9. company

> BUS(I)NESS

10. Dutch rice table

> RI(J)STTAFEL (is Indonesian food)

11. scoundrel

> BLAC(K)GUARD ("blaggard")

12. chat

> TA(L)K

13. his brain could not forget

> HYPER(M)NESIA

14. French man

> MO(N)SIEUR

15. more than one person

> PE(O)PLE

16. brilliant blue gem

> SA(P)PHIRE

17. a card game which sounded like 500

> CIN(Q)-CENTS

18. crew's living quarters

> FO(R)ECASTLE ("fo'c'sle")

19. British nobility

> VI(S)COUNT

20. missionary

> APOS(T)LE

21. deposits on his teeth

> PLAQ(U)E

22. coin worth 10 of what he was accused of stealing

> SIL(V)ER (5p piece, "siller")

23. double

> T(W)O

24. a French suburb

> PUTEAU(X) (there are probably many of these; Issy-les-Moulineaux is another)

25. ask a higher power for help

> PRA(Y)

26. meet up

> RENDE(Z)VOUS

Bonus. Where the words came from:

> ? I found some at wordplays.com, a crossword-solver, but they're not all there. RIJSTTAFEL is not, but I knew that one.

Comment: Nicely done! I had a couple of different words - rot13(N - yvne, R - gjvgpurq, Z - cnazarfvn, I - svircrapr, K - snhkobhet, L - cenlre), but yours work too. 

As for where the words came from, the "V" at the start is definitely not silent... ;)